# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; - Not sure what is wrong in code

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create trigger as below but getting error specified below. Can any one please help me to figure out what is wrong with the code. Thank you in advance

**Code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER TEST_DATA.IVR_SEQ
BEFORE INSERT ON TEST_DATA.TRANSACTION 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT TEST_DATA.IVR_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :new.IVRID 
  FROM dual;
END;
/
```

**Error:**

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:   ;

**Tool:** Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

Strange, as there's nothing wrong with it, but I get the same error as you do when executing it literally.

```
SQL> create or replace -- EDITIONABLE
  2    trigger scott.trg_ivr_seq
  3    before insert on scott.transaction
  4    for each row
  5  begin
  6    select scott.ivr_seq.nextval
  7    into :new.ivrid
  8    from dual;

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err trigger trg_ivr_Seq
Errors for TRIGGER TRG_IVR_SEQ:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/11     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
         one of the following:
         ;
```

(`editionable` is not an option in my 11gXE so I removed it).

As you can see, error points to line #4, column #11 which is

```
4    for each row
```

---

Rewritten from scratch (and "improved" a little bit):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger scott.ivr_seq
  2    before insert on scott.transaction
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.ivrid := scott.ivr_seq.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

---

It works with `select` as well (just that you wouldn't think that it is wrong):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger scott.ivr_seq
  2    before insert on scott.transaction
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select scott.ivr_seq.nextval
  6      into :new.ivrid
  7      from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

---

So ... rewrite it. I don't see any garbage characters (in Notepad++), I have no idea what's wrong with it.

---

**[EDIT]**

Luke Woodward's comment made me do another test. Yes, Luke is right!

Comment in the 1st line, before actually stating what I'm creating causes an error:

```
SQL> create or replace -- comment
  2    trigger trg_test
  3    before insert on dept
  4    for each row
  5  begin
  6    null;
```

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

But, comment in the 1st line AFTER stating what's being created doesn't cause any errors:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger -- comment here
  2    trg_test
  3    before insert on dept
  4    for each row
  5  begin
  6    null;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Thank you, Luke!

Comment: I think the problem here is that the comment after `CREATE OR REPLACE` confuses SQL\*Plus's detection of whether you've entered something that contains PL/SQL (such as a type, trigger, function, procedure or trigger).  If you're entering PL/SQL, SQL\*Plus can't terminate the input at the next semicolon: it has to wait for a line containing only a `/` before sending the statement to the database.  It seems to assume you've entered something that can't contain PL/SQL (e.g. `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` or `CREATE TABLE`) and so sends the statement off to the database as soon as it hits the `;`.

Comment: Also I think the line numbers are relative to the trigger body, not including the `before insert...` and `for each` clauses.  So line 1 is `begin`, line 4 contains `from dual;`, and indeed we have the semicolon at character 11 in this line.

Comment: Thank you, @Luke! I did another test, based on what you've said and - yes, you're right, it is a comment that causes problems.

Comment: Thank you @LukeWoodward and Littlefoot for your time and analysis, but I am still not clear how to resolve this error, any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: @user3542274: what version of Oracle are you using?  Does it help if you remove the keyword `EDITIONABLE`?  If I create a suitable user, table and sequence then your trigger compiles fine for me on Oracle 18c XE.  If, like Littlefoot, you are using an older version, you may have to remove this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can get this error:

1. Your SQL is malformed, you are missing a ; somewhere

   - Not present in the provided snippet.
2. Your SQL is malformed, the parser is being tripped up and believes things to be things they are not, finally failing when it get to the end of the file.

   - Not obviously present in the provided snippet. However i can't test the `EDITIONABLE` clause as it is not present in my db version, so it may be introducing some addition required syntax.
3. Your interface is mangling the SQL before it sends it to the database to be compiled.

   - Unlikely as SQL developer is way better at not doing this than SQL*Plus was, but if you have any custom configuration there are all kinds of things that could be happening, check what is actually getting to the database by looking at trigger in the database and see if it matches what you expect to be there.
4. Invalid characters in your code

   - Not a common issue but can be eliminated by either retyping the trigger manually, not using copy paste, or by pasting from a know clean source. (copy/paste from the web can include lots of weird character replacements used to get the layout right in the browser (no-break spaces, etc.), and apps like word can mangle things like quotes (e.g.Word replaces ' ' with ‘ ’)
5. Code in the same file before the trigger definition that has errors.

   - I am assuming you have run this separately from any other code, but if not put this trigger create statement in its own file and run it there.
6. Scenario 2 is being triggered by a non obvious misparse of the code.

   - This could be caused by other objects in this or a different schema with identical names, keyword use, etc. and can depend on which schema is running the DDL statement.
   - Try quoting `TEST_DATA.TRANSACTION` as `TEST_DATA."TRANSACTION"`, `TRANSACTION` is a keyword in oracle, and while some keywords can be used in some contexts, possibly your version of oracle is treating it as a keyword and messing up the rest of the parsing. This compiles fine on my DB without the quotes so i would lean more toward the next possibility, but I have this issue with a schema named "SEARCH" on my database, in some contexts you need to quote the name to prevent compile errors.
   - Check for name reuse on schemas, tables, views, etc. In your example your trigger and your sequence have the same name `TEST_DATA.IVR_SEQ`. On its own this is not an issue, but can cause seemingly random compile errors  depending on where the duplication is.
     I could not reproduce your specific compile error, but I was able to create a few different compile errors by creating different name collisions (example creating a table in the `TEST_DATA` schema named `TEST_DATA`, creating a function named `TEST_DATA`, creating a package, sequence named `TEST_DATA`, a function named `IVR_SEQ` in a package named `TEST_DATA`, etc.). It is possible on your version of Oracle this or a similar collision is creating the EOF error.